# CSS problem in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css

I have a huge problem with my webpage ([www.icls.ro](http://www.icls.ro)). It is looking fine in Firefox4 but the elements are not placed in their places in Internet Explorer 9. I suppose it is a CSS compatibility problem. I use the following style.css file:

```
    *{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
img{border:0px;}
html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image:url(images/bg.gif);
background-position:top left;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
body{
width:980px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:25px 0 0 0;
}
.logo{
float:left;
margin:0 21px 0 0
}
#menu{
float:left;
margin:0 0 3px 0;
}
#menu li{
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
}
#menu img{
float:left;
}
.links{
display:block;
line-height:23px;
height:23px;
text-align:right;
padding:0 50px 18px 0
}
.links a{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
color:#000000;
margin:0 13px;
text-decoration:none
}
.block{
background-image:url(images/block_bg.jpg);
background-position:top left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:238px;
height:251px;
float:left;
padding:46px 0 0 24px;
margin:0 21px 0 0;
/ margin:0 18px 0 0
}
.block p{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
color:#0B3556;
display:block;
width:200px;
padding:0 0 20px 0;
}
#content{
padding:25px 0 35px 0;
overflow:hidden;
}
.line{
width:937px;
overflow:hidden;
border-bottom:1px solid #CEC7B9;
margin:0 0 27px 0
}
.sidebar{
width:238px;
float:left;
padding:0 21px 30px 24px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#545353
}
.sidebar h4{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#040404;
line-height:48px;
}
.sidebar p{
padding:0 0 25px 0
}



.list{
background-color:#FAF3E5;
float:left;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
.list ul{
padding:23px 0 0 25px;
}
.list li{
list-style-type:none;
}
.list span{
color:#105183;
display:block;
float:left;
width:32px;
}
.list p{
display:block;
float:left;
color:#545353;
width:550px;
padding:0 45px 15px 0
}



.news{
padding:23px 0 0 0;
}
.news p{
padding:0px;
}
.news span{
display:block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
color:#105183;
font-weight:bold;
padding:0 0 12px 0
}
.news a{
color:#105183;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.news a:visited{text-decoration:underline}
.news a:hover{text-decoration:none}
.pad25{
margin:0 0 25px 0;
}
.infoblock{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#545353;
width:272px;
float:left;
padding:0 29px 0 24px;
}
.pic{
padding:18px 0;
}
.infoblock a{
color:#105183;
text-decoration:underline
}
.infoblock a:visited{text-decoration:underline}
.infoblock a:hover{text-decoration:none}
.infoblock p{
padding:0 0 30px 0
}
.border{
border-right:1px solid #E8E5DE
}
#footer{
width:980px;
float:left;
background-color:#FAF3E6;
line-height:60px;
height:60px;
padding:0 0 0 25px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
color:#73706A;
}
#footer a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#73706A;
}
#footer a:visited{text-decoration:none}
#footer a:hover{text-decoration:underline}



#content .inner_copy {border:0;color:#f00;float:left;width:50%!important;margin:-202px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden;line-height:0;padding:0;font-size:12px}
```

How is this caused and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Your doctype triggers [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

When IE is in Quirks Mode, it's pretending to be IE 5.5.

Change it to this and the problem will be fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Although in most cases, you should just use the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Say hi to Standards Mode.

Relevant information: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: thank you for your fast response. i've changed the doctype, now the page looks better but the element are stil not proper alligned. please take a look

Comment: I would go ahead and change it to `<!doctype html>` but it your choice.

Comment: @Lime: His HTML looks more like HTML4 to me, that's why I didn't suggest it. A prime example: `<body link="#0D00ED" vlink="#0D00ED" alink="#0D00ED">`

Comment: @sorin: Try setting `.list { width: 654px }`

Comment: Although some of the HTML4 elements have been deprecated, HTML5 is 100% backwards compatible.  Font elements, frames, etc. should still be recognized along with the body attributes.  A prime example of this is google.  I mean seriously google is often a natzi about being backwards compatible.  Look at the source of google's homepage `<!doctype html>......<body bgcolor=#ffffff text=#000000 link=#0000cc vlink=#551a8b alink=#ff0000 onload....>`  HTML5 doctype and HTML4 deprecated attributes work together.

Comment: Thank you so much! I belive it looks just fine now. Thank you again my firend!:D

Comment: One more thing.. I can see that there is still some small diference between the firefox and the ie9 page display. Look at the text in the bottom-left part of the index page. In IE9 the word "acestora" is on a new line.. Any thoughts?

Comment: @sorin: That's not really a problem, is it? :) http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ - I think it's just because IE9 and Firefox 4 render fonts slightly differently. For what it's worth, setting the size to `13px` makes them look more similar.

Comment: Not a problem, you are right:) Thank you for your help. Have a nice day!